# Write String Variable into one byte of byte array like bytes[6] = "c6"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, serial-port, hex

I would like to know how I would proceed in order to write some strings into one byte of a byte array (running C# WinForms in MS Visual 2015 Community edition).

I have a control board that controls a step motor. In order to send commands to the motor via the `SerialPort` the board needs a byte array of length 9.

In each byte of the array there is an information stored (like board adress, motor number etc.) The last 3 bytes in this array are for the speed. From the source code of the program that the producer ships with it, sometimes the information that I need to send looks like this : "b0", "bc", "a7" etc. How can I write this into the array in the desired place. Currently, I have it like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] a = new byte[9];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 1;
    a[2] = 0;
    a[3] = 0;
    a[4] = 0;
    a[5] = 0;
    a[6] = 02;                     //could also be like "bc"
    a[7] = Convert.ToByte("bc");   // if its a number from 00 to
    a[8] = Convert.ToByte("c0");   // 99 the motor works as planned

    serialPort1.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
}
```

If I have normal numbers from 0 to 99 in byte 6-9 the motor runs as intended. But higher speed have string values. Why the variables look the way they look I'll figure out later, but from my plan now a manual input would be fine as the motor is supposed to run at only one speed anyway.

So far my complete code does compile, but after sending I get :

> FormatExceptionError{"Inputstring has wrong format."}

I found questions of how to convert a complete string into a complete byte array but those did not really help me.

Comment: @TripleEEE : [**Of course it does**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: why do you need it as string? the rest of the positions is filled obviously with bytes.

Comment: @TripleEEE : [**Actually it does have that too**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TripleEEE : Isn't IntelliSense showing them to you? Or from where did you get that they wouldn't exist?

Comment: @VisualVincent okay, you're right. Though MSDN tells:*Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.* which is not a string like "bc" - I'll delete my other comment, though it's wrong. You're right with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not string values. They are [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representations of each byte. Use `0x` as a prefix to indicate hexadecimal values.

```
a[7] = 0xBC;
a[8] = 0xC0;
```

Comment: thanks alot, worked perfectly and motor is turning as i want to. I thought hexadecimal were very long values , hence i though it was some string =)

Answer (score 4):

You need to [**specify the base**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k(v=vs.110).aspx) of the input string:

```
a[7] = Convert.ToByte("bc", 16);
a[8] = Convert.ToByte("c0", 16);
```

Base 16 is hexadecimal.

Comment: thanks a lot, worked as well but i used the 0x prefix as mentioned in the other answer.